# Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Gutentag, guys!

I keep getting this error message from my application after unmounting the component:

```
Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in Header (at index.js:27)
```

Now here is the code from the Header component:

```
class Header extends Component {
  isCancelled = false;
  state = {
    someStateVars: x,
    separateColumns: 'true',
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    if (!this.isCancelled) {
      this.setState({ //######THIS IS LINE 27######
        [name]: value
      });
    }
  }

  handleDisplayChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    const name = 'separateColumns';

    if (!this.isCancelled) {
      this.setState({  
        [name]: value
      }, () => {
        this.props.displayChange();
      });
    }
  }

  serversRefresh = () => {

    if (!this.isCancelled) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({refreshed: false});
      }, localStorage.getItem('seconds')*1000); //disable refresh for 15 seconds
    }
  }

  reactivateButton = () => {
    if (!this.isCancelled) this.setState({refreshed: false});
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('seconds')>5 && !this.isCancelled){
      this.setState({refreshed: true});
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.isCancelled = true;
  }
}
```

When I saw I was getting this error, I've added isCancelled variable which is changed in componentWillUnmount() function to true.

After I unmount the Header component, after 15 seconds, when the serversRefreshbutton is reactivated, I get this error message.

How can I fix it?

On another component where I've encountered this issue "isCancelled" var did help, but here I see it has no impact and the issue persists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just store your timeout in a variable, e.g.

```
this.timeout = setTimeout(/* your actions here*/, /* your timeout */)
```

and then clear your timeout in the `componentWillUnmount`

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout)
}
```

It should fix your problem without crutches like `this.isCancelled`. Detecting component's mount state is no-op, because it still unloaded from memory even after unmounting.

`setTimeout` returns timer's id with which it can be cancelled in future. `clearTimeout` cancels timeout by it's id, if it is not yet executed.

More about your case you can read here: [Why isMounted is antipattern](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html).

More about timers on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout).

Comment: i have a clearInterval in my componentWillUnmount and yet i'm still getting this error